# mysql_query not getting expected results. Blank Screen at output

Tags: php, mysql

When I enter a wrong query from the database such as entering an actors name which is not in the database, the output is a blank screen. The following is the code:

```
$resul1 = mysql_query("select website from actors where name = '$find_actor';");

if (!$resul1) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Actor: '.$find_actor.' does not exist.' . $query;
    die($message);  
}
else {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resul1)) {
    echo "The actor, ".$find_actor." website is ".$row[0];
}
}
```

So, entering a name which is in the database, I get the correct results. The problem, however, is that entering a name no in the database leads to a white blank screen. 
I'm supposed to get the $message result, but do not.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $resul1 = mysql_query("select website from actors where name = '$find_actor';");

      if (mysql_num_rows($resul1) === 0) {
        $message .= 'Actor: '.$find_actor.' does not exist.' . $query;
        die($message);  
       }
      else {
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resul1)) {
         echo "The actor, ".$find_actor." website is ".$row[0];
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `if (mysql_num_rows($resul1) == 0) {` and that should show your error message.